# Discord.py - Bot does not respond to commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

> When I write the command "! LVL" The bot just doesn't react in any
> way. The teams used to work. I changed something and now he does not
> react to them. In addition, before, if I wrote a command incorrectly,
> then in the console the bot gave an error that such a command does not
> exist. Now he does not respond to more than one command, even to the
> built-in one !help

> But all events work correctly.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio
import time
import os

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True
intents.voice_states = True
intents.integrations = True
intents.invites = True
intents.presences = True
intents.webhooks = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents=intents)
cluster = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
colluser = cluster.chill.user
collclan = cluster.chill.clans
collshop = cluster.chill.shop


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot connected to the server")

    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            post = {
                "_id": member.id,
                "name": member.mention,
                "user": member.name,
                "inventory": [],
                "warms": 0,
                "mute": 0,
                "voice_activ": 0,
                "localban": 0,
                "register": member.created_at,
                "onservfrom": member.joined_at,
                "clan": 0,
                "marry": 0,
                "love": 0,
                "childs": [],
                "balance": 0,
                "bank": 0,
                "rep": 0,
                "cdxp": 0,
                "cnxp": 0,
                "dxp": 0,
                "nxp": 0,
                "cdbal": 0,
                "cdlvl": 1,
                "cnlvl": 1,
                "dlvl": 1,
                "nlvl": 1
            }

            if colluser.count_documents({"_id": member.id}) == 0:
                colluser.insert_one(post)

@client.event
async def on_guild_role_create(role):
    print("new role created")
    post = {
        "_id": role.id,
        "titel": "none",
        "cp": [],
        "exp": 0,
        "lvl": 0,
        "maxcp": 7,
        "bank": 0
    }

    if collclan.count_documents({"role_id": role.id}) == 0:
        collclan.insert_one(post)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.webhook_id:
        return
    f1 = colluser
    f2 = colluser

    f4 = colluser
    user = message.author
    data = colluser.find_one({"_id": user.id})
    dtn = datetime.today().strftime("%I:%M %p")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    day = data["dxp"]
    dark = data["nxp"]
    dl = data["dlvl"]
    nl = data["nlvl"]
    balanc = data["balance"]
    dexp = 500 + 100 * dl
    nexp = 500 + 100 * nl
    if not data["cdbal"] == "0":
        return
    if len(message.clean_content) >= 15:
        print("Сообщение длинее 15 символов")
        bal = 6
        exp = 6
    if len(message.clean_content) <= 14:
        print("Сообщение короче 15 символов")
        bal = 3
        exp = 3
    if any(("AM" in dtn) for AM in dtn):
        print("time is AM")
        colluser.update_one({"_id": user.id},
            {"$set": {"dxp": + exp}})
    if any(("PM" in dtn) for PM in dtn):
        print("time is PM")
        colluser.update_one({"_id": user.id},
        {"$set": {"nxp": + exp}})
    if data["dxp"] >= 500 + 100 * dl:
        print(f"Новый уровень светлой стороны у пользователя {user}")
        colluser.update_one({"_id": user.id},
            {"$set": {"dlvl": dl + 1}})
        colluser.update_one({"_id": user.id},
            {"$set": {"dxp": day - dexp}})
    if data["nxp"] >= 500 + 100 * nl:
        print(f"Новый уровень темной стороны у пользователя {user}")
        colluser.update_one({"_id": user.id},
            {"$set": {"nlvl": nl + 1}})
        colluser.update_one({"_id": user.id},
            {"$set": {"nxp": dark - nexp}})
    print(f"Пользователь {user} написал сообшение")
    f1.update_one({"_id": user.id},
        {"$set": {"balance": balanc + bal}})
    print("F1")
    f2.update_one({"_id": user.id},
        {"$set": {"cdbal": "1"}})
    print("F2")
    await asyncio.sleep(40)
    print("F3")
    f4.update_one({"_id": user.id},
        {"$set": {"cdbal": "0"}})
    print("F4")

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    data = colluser.find_one({"_id": member.id})
    day = data["dxp"]
    dark = data["nxp"]
    dl = data["dlvl"]
    nl = data["nlvl"]
    dexp = 500 + 100 * dl
    nexp = 500 + 100 * nl
    guild = client.guilds[0]
    guild_id = 830565202276909056
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        print("1")
        t1 = time.time()
        colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
            {"$set": {"voice_tim1": t1}})
    elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
        dtn = datetime.today().strftime("%I:%M %p")
        t1 = data["voice_tim1"]
        voice_activ1 = data["voice_activ"]
        balance = data["balance"]
        t2 = time.time()
        tim = t2-t1
        print("0")
        print(dtn)
        colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
            {"$set": {"voice_activ": voice_activ1 + tim}})
        colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
            {"$set": {"balance": balance + tim / 12}})
        if any(("AM" in dtn) for AM in dtn):
            print("time is AM")
            colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
                {"$set": {"dxp": day + tim / 4}})
        if any(("PM" in dtn) for PM in dtn):
            print("time is PM")
            colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
                {"$set": {"nxp": dark + tim / 4}})
        if data["dxp"] >= 500 + 100 * dl:
            colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
                {"$set": {"dlvl": dl + 1}})
            colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
                {"$set": {"dxp": day - dexp}})
        if data["nxp"] >= 500 + 100 * nl:
            colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
                {"$set": {"nlvl": nl + 1}})
            colluser.update_one({"_id": member.id},
                {"$set": {"nxp": dark - nexp}})
        if dl >> nl:
            role_id1 = 869267468047220856
            role_id2 = 869267490851676200
            role1 = guild.get_role(role_id1)
            role2 = guild.get_role(role_id2)
            await member.add_roles(role1, reason="Роль выдана за превоблодания уровня света")
            await member.remove_roles(role2, reason="Роль снята за превоблодания уровня света")
        if nl >> dl:
            role_id1 = 869267468047220856
            role_id2 = 869267490851676200
            role1 = guild.get_role(role_id1)
            role2 = guild.get_role(role_id2)
            await member.add_roles(role2, reason="Роль выдана за превоблодания уровня тьмы")
            await member.remove_roles(role1, reason="Роль снята за превоблодания уровня тьмы")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    post = {
        "_id": member.id,
        "name": member.mention,
        "user": member.name,
        "inventory": [],
        "warms": 0,
        "mute": 0,
        "voice_activ": 0,
        "localban": 0,
        "register": member.created_at,
        "onservfrom": member.joined_at,
        "clan": 0,
        "marry": 0,
        "love": 0,
        "childs": [],
        "balance": 0,
        "bank": 0,
        "xp": 0,
        "dxp": 0,
        "nxp": 0,
        "cdbal": 0,
        "lvl": 1,
        "dlvl": 1,
        "nlvl": 1
    }

    if colluser.count_documents({"_id": member.id}) == 0:
        colluser.insert_one(post)

@client.command()
async def lvl(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    print("test")
    if member is None:
        member = message.author
    else:
        data = colluser.find_one({"_id": member.id})
        nnexp = 500 + 100 * data["nlvl"]
        ndexp = 500 + 100 * data["dlvl"]
        dnnexp = nnexp - data["nxp"]
        dndexp = dndexp -data["dxp"]
        if data["voice_activ"] >= 60:
            vcm = data["voice_activ"] / 60
            if vcm >= 60:
                vch = vcm / 60
                if vch >= 24:
                    vcd = vch /24
                    vca = vch
                else:
                    vca = vch
                    t = "часов"
            else:
                vca = vcm
                t = "минут"
        else:
            t = "Секунд"
            vca = data["voice_activ"]
        lvleb = discord.Embed(colour=role.color)
        lvleb.set_author(name=f"Профиль пользователя: {member}", icon_url=member.avatar_url)
        lvleb.add_field(name="Уровень света", value=data["nlvl"], inline=True)
        lvleb.add_field(name="Уровень тьмы", value=data["dlvl"], inline=True)
        lvleb.add_field(name="Опыт света", value=f"{data['nlvl']} / {dnnexp}", inline=True)
        lvleb.add_field(name="Опыт тьмы", value=f"{data['dlvl']} / {dndexp}", inline=True)
        lvleb.add_field(name="Время в войсе", value=f"{vca}{t}", inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=lvleb)

@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)

    if isinstance(error, commands.UserInputError):
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"Правильное использование команды: `{ctx.prefix}{ctx.command.name}` ({ctx.command.brief}): `{ctx.prefix}{ctx.command.usage}`"
        ))


client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: You can also just do `discord.Intents.all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of your `on_message` event

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working